# How to read text\plain message in Response output?

Tags: java, rest, response, httpresponse

I'm testing REST API and while I make POST call like following, it's resulting into 400 bad request and in output it's returning message which has media type `text/plain`:

```
Entity<T> entity = Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
Response response = createRequest(path).post(entity);
```

where `createRequest` method returns `Invocation.Builder` like -

```
Invocation.Builder builder = createWebTarget(path).request(Type).header("Authorization", "AR-JWT " + authenticationToken);
```

I want to read the message which is in `text/plain`, I tried with -

```
response.readEntity(Class<T> entityType);
```

but there I could not find class which would take `text/plain`

Could you please help me how can I read `text/plain` message in output?

I'm using following:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
```

Comment: You mean `text/plain`, right?

Comment: Yes, it's `text/plain`, I checked it with `response.getMediaType()`

Comment: did you try `response.readEntity(String.class)`?

Comment: Yes, this worked!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If it's useful, you could also create JAX RS annotations such as @ApiOperation ( produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) and set the output that way

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

```
String res = response.readEntity(String.class)
```